# Implementing custom AvroConverter for confluent kafka-connect-s3

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I am using [Confluent's Kafka s3 connect](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3) for copying data from apache Kafka to AWS S3.

The problem is that I have Kafka data in AVRO format which is NOT using Confluent Schema Registry’s Avro serializer and I cannot change the Kafka producer. So I need to deserialize existing Avro data from Kafka and then persist the same in parquet format in AWS S3. I tried using confluent's AvroConverter as value converter like this -

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost/api/v1/avro
```

And i am getting this error -

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic dcp-all to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

As far as I understand, "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter" will only work if the data is written in Kafka using Confluent Schema Registry’s Avro serializer and hence I am getting this error. So my question is Do I need to implement a generic AvroConverter in this case? And if yes, how do I extend the existing source code - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud?

Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend that repo. You just need to [implement a `Converter`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.java) (part of Apache Kafka) shade it into a JAR, then place it on your Connect worker's `CLASSPATH`, like [BlueApron did for Protobuf](https://github.com/blueapron/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter)

Or see if this works - https://github.com/farmdawgnation/registryless-avro-converter

---

> NOT using Confluent Schema Registry

Then what registry *are* you using? Each one that I know of has configurations to interface with the Confluent one

Comment: thanks for your reply. My avro schema is hosted on a http endpoint - http://localhost/api/v1/avro. As far as i know, Confluent Schema Registry’s Avro serializer, has its own wire format and hence if Confluent's Avroserializer is not used for serialization, it can't be deserialized using Confluent's Avro deserializer. In my case, I don't have control on the producer of data. So can't change the Avroserializer used while serialization. So the only option left is that I write my custom Avro deserializer as explained by you. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Endpoints and wire formats are two different things. As long as your registry accepts the same API requests, your own Registry would work fine with Confluent's. For example, see Hortonworks Registry - https://github.com/hortonworks/registry/blob/master/docs/confluent.rst